# edit variable name at run time and also create new variable at run time

Tags: java, c

Dear Member and visitors,

I am starting a project and want such facility to edit variable name at run time as the requirement of user and also can create new variable at run time. Any idea???

Comment: Why would you even want to do that?

Comment: Most likely an [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @Turing85 Could be. Do you actually need to create/rename variables at runtime or would it be enougth to emulate this?

Comment: Dear Gumbo,i am trying to make a project named expenses management system and every person has different expenses like i used alcohol but u do not have that expenses. This is one example there can be more than like this so as per u what should i do

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should look into objects where you have key/value pairs like [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for example. In this case you can change name and value of any variable.